# Extend box around equation to the entire line

Tags: amsmath, boxes

My question is simple: I use `\boxed` from the `amsmath` package and so far so good.

The single issue I have is that I use the boxed environment on its own line, but the box is only around the equation, not the entire line.

Example code:

```
  \[  \boxed{ p(v,h) = \frac{1}{Z} e ^{-E(v,h)} }  \]
```

How can I extend the box to the entire line?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the environment `mdframed` instead of the command `\boxed`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}
\[  p(v,h) = \frac{1}{Z} e ^{-E(v,h)}  \]
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you need any background you can add a `backgroundcolor` option to the `mdframed` environment.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mdframed,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=green!10]
\[  p(v,h) = \frac{1}{Z} e ^{-E(v,h)} \]
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=cyan!20]
\begin{equation}
  p(v,h) = \frac{1}{Z} e ^{-E(v,h)}
\end{equation}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a little more unusual, but in the end it lets you keep the equation numbering and lets you highlight the box containing the equation.

To achieve that I defined a `\newcommand` which I called `\fancyboxed` which has the following synopsis:

`\fancyboxed[<background color>]{<equation>}`

Please note that in this case the argument `<equation>` is already in math mode, so you don't have to insert things such as `$...$`, `\[...\]`, etc.

The basic idea behind my solution was to treat the equation as the argument of a (rectangular) tikz node spanning the entire `\linewidth`.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}          %drawing
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}        %dummy text
\newcommand{\fancyboxed}[2][white]{      %white is default background
  \begin{equation}
    \tikz \node at(0,0) [shape=rectangle,draw,thick,minimum width=\linewidth,fill=#1] {$\displaystyle #2$};
\end{equation}
  }
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\fancyboxed{p(v,h) = \frac{1}{Z} e ^{-E(v,h)}}
\fancyboxed[red!30]{p(v,h) = \frac{1}{Z} e ^{-E(v,h)}}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]