# Colorbox with changes package

Tags: color, changes

I am working with the `changes` package. Modifying the color of the changed passages works well with `\colorlet` command. Is it possible to create colorboxes (with yellow color) only around the changes (without the `\colorbox` command)?

Thanks for your answer...
Philipp

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show some minimal code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control the appearance of added and deleted text through the commands `\setaddedmarkup` and `\setdeletedmarkup`, respectively.

So you can define, for example:

```
\setaddedmarkup{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}
\setdeletedmarkup{\colorbox{red}{\sout{#1}}}
```

With the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{changes}

\definechangesauthor[name={Philipp}]{P}

\setaddedmarkup{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}
\setdeletedmarkup{\colorbox{red}{\sout{#1}}}

\begin{document}
This is \added[id=P]{new} text.

This is \deleted[id=P]{bad} text.

This is \replaced[id=P]{nice}{bad} text.
\end{document}
```

you get

[image]

This doesn't obviously support line breaks.

If you don't need particular formatting apart from coloring, you can load the `soul` package (once loaded by `changes`), and define, for example:

```
\setaddedmarkup{\sethlcolor{yellow}\hl{#1}}
\setdeletedmarkup{\sethlcolor{red}\hl{#1}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{soul}

\definechangesauthor[name={Philipp}]{P}

\setaddedmarkup{\sethlcolor{yellow}\hl{#1}}
\setdeletedmarkup{\sethlcolor{red}\hl{#1}}

\begin{document}
This is \added[id=P]{new} text.

This is \deleted[id=P]{bad} text.

This is \replaced[id=P]{nice}{bad} text.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Otherwise, have a look at this thread for more highlighting possibilities: [Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex)

Comment: Line breaks would be quite annoying like this ;)

Comment: @percusse Of course it doesn't support line breaks.... :-)

Comment: It needs more soul http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it also possible to add markups for equations (created with align)?

Comment: @Philipp It is possible, but not with the `changes` package. See this answer of mine: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156032/27635 for an example

Comment: Thanks Karl. Is there any possibility that an equation can be boxed only in the draft mode although package CHANGES does not work?

Comment: @Philipp I don't know, I'm sorry. Please ask a new question for this.